# spring mvc error : BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, exception, model-view-controller

I got an error in spring mvc while downloading a file from server.I am unable to find the error.please help me..

controller is:

```
@Controller
public class CareerController {

    //inject objects of dao class
    @Autowired
    CareerDAO cardao;

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    //inject objects of dao class
    // @Autowired
    // VacancyDAO Vdao;
    //inject objects of JavaMailSender class
    @Autowired
    private MailMail m;

    public void setM(MailMail m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void setCardao(CareerDAO cardao) {
        this.cardao = cardao;
    }

    String resPath = "C:\\Users\\Anjana\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IntelliLabsWeb\\build\\web\\uploads\\";

    public String getResPath() {
        return resPath;
    }

    public void setResPath(String resPath) {
        this.resPath = resPath;
    }

    //go to careers page from index page
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    @RequestMapping("/careersPage")
    public ModelAndView ViewVacancyForPublic() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/AllVacancies");
    }

    //go to Job Application Form 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping("/ApplicationForm")
    public ModelAndView Apply() {
        return new ModelAndView("careers/ApplicationForm", "command", new Career());
    }



    //delete applicant only by admin
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteProfile/{a_id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteProfile(@PathVariable int a_id) {

        if (cardao.deletion(a_id) == 1) {
            System.out.println("Profile " + a_id + " deleted\n");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ShowApplicants");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/failiure");
        }

    }

    //show one profile for admin
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/oneProfile/{a_id}")
    public ModelAndView viewOneProfile(@PathVariable int a_id) {
        Career prof = cardao.retrieveProfile(a_id);

        prof.setResumePath(resPath);

        System.out.println("\n\nid : " + prof.getA_id());
        System.out.println("name : " + prof.getName());
        System.out.println("path" + prof.getResumePath());
        System.out.println("date : " + prof.getDateApplied() + "\n\n");

        List<Career> profList = new ArrayList<>();
        profList.add(prof);
        return new ModelAndView("admin/ViewOneProfile", "profile", prof);
    }

    //method doUpload -- uploads file to uploads folder
    //********************************************************************
    private File doUpload(HttpServletRequest request, Career career) {

        String Aname = career.getName();
        System.out.println("Name: " + Aname);

        // Root Directory.
        String uploadRootPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads");
        //ie,create a folder named "uploads" under the project's Web Pages folder.
        //otherwise nullpointer exception will be thrown. 
        //actually,program creates the directory if it doesn't exists.
        //just don't forget to put the slash(/) in getRealPath("/uploads")
        System.out.println("uploadRootPath=" + uploadRootPath);

        File uploadRootDir = new File(uploadRootPath);
        // Create directory if it not exists.
        if (!uploadRootDir.exists()) {
            uploadRootDir.mkdirs();
        }

        CommonsMultipartFile fileData = career.getFileDatas();

        // Client File Name
        String name = fileData.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println("Client File Name = " + name);

        File serverFile = null;

        if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
            try {
                // Create the file on server
                serverFile = new File(uploadRootDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);

                // Stream to write data to file in server.
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(fileData.getBytes());
                stream.close();
                //

                System.out.println("Write file: " + serverFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error Write file: " + name);
            }
        }

        // model.addAttribute("Aname", Aname);
        //model.addAttribute("resumeFile", serverFile); 
        return serverFile;

    }

    //download resume
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------  
     @RequestMapping(value="/download",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadPDFResource(@RequestParam("myResName") String fileName,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response){
           // @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {

         System.out.println("filename i got :"+fileName);
        //If user is not authorized - he should be thrown out from here itself

        //String fileName="Ente Kadha - Madhavikkutty.pdf";

        //Authorized user will download the file
        String dataDirectory = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/downloads/");
        Path file = Paths.get(dataDirectory, fileName);
        if (Files.exists(file)) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            try {
                Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nFile not found!!\n\n");
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="DAO"></context:component-scan>

    <!--<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>-->

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <!--<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"   
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <bean id="con" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intelliLABS"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>   
        <property name="password" value="root"></property> 

        <!--
        //for ms sql server,it may be like :
        database-driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/simplehr;instance=SQLEXPRESS
        username=shoppingcart
        password=12345
        -->     
    </bean>

    <!--    normal jdbc template bean-->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="con"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- For sending email,adding spring's mail support -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />  
        <property name="username" value="thisisanjusdummyacc@gmail.com" />  
        <property name="password" value="thisisdummy" />  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailMail" class="bean.MailMail">  
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />  
    </bean>  

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="contactsDAO" class="DAO.ContactsDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="vacancyDAO" class="DAO.VacancyDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc1" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="careerDAO" class="DAO.CareerDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc2" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

viewOneProfile.jsp is :

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ViewOneProfile
    Created on : 13 Sep, 2017, 2:23:42 PM
    Author     : Anjana
--%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>

            <th><h3>${profile.name}</h3></th>
        <tr>
            <td>Application Id :</td>
            <td>${profile.a_id}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td>${profile.name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address :</td>
            <td>${profile.address}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>${profile.email}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>${profile.phone}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vacancy id:</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Applied :</td>
            <td>${profile.dateApplied}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <form:form method="post" action="download">
            <td>Resume :  ${profile.resumePath}${profile.resumeDoc} </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" path="myResName" value="${profile.resumeDoc}" /></td>
            <td> <input type="submit" value="download"/> </td>
        </form:form>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

apache log shows :

```
21-Sep-2017 16:05:00.467 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.UserDAO controller.regController.userdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5192)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1744)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.UserDAO controller.regController.userdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 35 more

21-Sep-2017 16:05:00.467 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet /SpringLogin threw load() exception
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5192)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1744)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I thought the way i used to pass the fileName from jsp page to spring controller
is wrong.I tried many ways to pass the value from jsp...but nothing works.

The browser just shows an error as "the request sent by the client is syntactically incorrect."
but what is that syntax error?

Comment: From the log, Inside your RegController class you are autowiring UserDao but it is not configured as a bean

Comment: but the problem is i don't have a class named RegController in the project.

Comment: Maybe some other name with @Controller("regController") ?

Comment: If not, you can clean your build directory and rebuild project, simply by mvn clean package if you are using maven. If not maven, look for similar functionality in your build system.